constexpr string not usable in constant expression if string created with addition operator
When setting a static constexpr string to another static constexpr string, c++ (gcc 14.2, -std=gnu++23) fails to compile if the source string was created by adding two strings together (std::string("a") + "b"), even if the string is under the (gcc specific?) restriction of 15 characters.
Creating the string via implicit conversion (string A = "ab") or explicitly (string B = std::string("ab")) works normally.
Strangely, preforming the addition operation in a constexpr function also works fine (string C() { return std::string("a") + "b"; }).
I am unsure why the above solutions compile successfully, but using a "+" directly in the variable declaration somehow makes the variable unusable in further constexprs.
See example code below:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static constexpr std::string A = "ab";
static constexpr std::string _A = A; //compiles

static constexpr std::string B = std::string("ab");
static constexpr std::string _B = B; //also compiles

static constexpr std::string C() { return std::string("a") + "b"; }
static constexpr std::string _C = C(); //also compiles

static constexpr std::string D = std::string("a") + "b";
static constexpr std::string _D = D; //error: the value of ‘D’ is not usable in a constant expression

int main() {
    std::cout
        << _A << std::endl
        << _B << std::endl
        << _C << std::endl
        << _D << std::endl;
}

(see code on Godbolt)

Might well be a compiler or standard library bug.  clang seems happy

It looks like a bug

It works fine in Microsoft's C++ compiler.

Whereas std::string is usable in constant expression, constexpr std::string is not supported (SSO might trick it though).

Your examples only work because of SSO (small string optimization, it avoids allocation for small strings). If you change any of the examples to use a longer string, the example won't work anymore.

@geza I did mention in the the question that (in GCC) constexpr strings are restricted to 15 characters.

@GunnarKnutson: is this 15-character thing guaranteed to work (i.e., it is documented), or just happens to work?

@geza I couldn't find any documentation on it, although that may just be because I am not familiar w/ gcc's documentation and couldn't track it down. However, I did find why it is 15 - that's the value of _S_local_capacity in basic_string.h. This value is used to set the size of string's internal char buffer, _M_local_buf, which is given the size of _S_local_capacity + 1. (Presumably the +1 is for a trailing \0). You can see this in the basic_string.h source code, line 209 (https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h;hb=HEAD#l209)

@GunnarKnutson: yep, you see the implementation of SSO. I think you didn't find this in the doc, because it is not documented. Therefore you shouldn't rely on this. If you use another standard library implementation that doesn't use SSO, your example program won't work at all. Changing internals of std::string happened at least once in the past (in the old days, the usual implementation of std::string used ref-counting. Now they use SSO instead). Couldn't you use std::array, which is guaranteed to work?

@gaza I could use std::array, but the reason I am using constexpr is for preformance reasons. I am not sure of the preformance considerations of constantly casting arrays to strings vs just making the string generation static instead of constexpr. I suppose I will have to look into that more.
